# Cannot upload cron.xml file to app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

After creating a new cron.xml file in my java project, when I upload my app to GAE, some errors occur:

Detail:

Verifying availability:

   Will check again in 1 seconds.

   Will check again in 2 seconds.

   Will check again in 4 seconds.

   Will check again in 8 seconds.

   Closing update: new version is ready to start serving.

Updating datastore:

   Uploading index definitions.

   Uploading cron jobs.com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/datastore/cron/update?app_id=aptosin&version=1&

500 Internal Server Error

Server Error (500)

A server error has occurred.

cron.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
 <cron>
  <url>/url</url>
  <description>Backup data 02 times per day</description>
  <schedule>every 12 hours</schedule>
  <timezone>America/New_York</timezone>
  <target>ah-builtin-python-bundle</target>
 </cron>
</cronentries>
```

The URL : /_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create?name=BackupDaily &kind=Datastore&kind=Datastore&filesystem= blobstore&gs_bucket_name=smsspamfilteraptosin

Can somebody tell me what is going wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: can you post contents of cron.xml here?

Comment: @PeterKnego I've uploaded my cron file